# Using Angular Bootstrap Typeahead. Trying to get value of json different than value shown

Tags: json, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a json object

```
states = { id:1, name: "Sales Manager" }
```

I have an input for typeahead

```
<input type="text" 
       placeholder="Position" 
       ng-model="position" 
       typeahead="title.name for title in states($viewValue)" />
```

When I select if uses the name variable and that is fine, but I need to set a hidden input with the selected id value from the json.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One way I might approach this, setup a watch on `position` in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('position', function() {
  selectedPositionId = getIdForPositionName($scope.position);
});
```

That way `selectedPositionId` will always be current to the value of `position` that the user has chosen.